# ObjectBinaryToText error with a TReader/TWriter helper class

Tags: pascal, fpc

I've created two simple helpers to make `TWriter.WriteProperties()` and `TReader.ReadProperty()` public, based on [this example](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/src/545933.flat).

It works fine when saving the persistent things in binary object format but fails when converting to text.

Any idea about how to make this working (text format)? I don't want to rewrite the conversion routines just for this.

The problem is illustrated in this simple console program:

```
program tfiler_persistent_hack;
{$MODE DELPHI}

uses
  classes, sysutils;

type

  TReaderEx = class helper for TReader
    procedure ReadPersistent(aValue: TPersistent);
  end;

  TWriterEx = class helper for TWriter
    procedure WritePersistent(aValue: TPersistent);
  end;

  TTest = class(TComponent)
  private
    fList: TStringList;
    procedure ListFromReader(aReader: TReader);
    procedure ListToWriter(aWriter: TWriter);
  protected
    procedure defineProperties(aFiler: TFiler); override;
  public
    constructor create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor destroy; override;
    property list: TStringList read fList;
  end;

  procedure TReaderEx.ReadPersistent(aValue: TPersistent);
  begin
    ReadListBegin;
    while not EndOfList do ReadProperty(aValue);
    ReadListEnd;
  end;

  procedure TWriterEx.WritePersistent(aValue: TPersistent);
  begin
    WriteListBegin;
    WriteProperties(aValue);
    WriteListEnd;
  end;

  procedure TTest.ListFromReader(aReader: TReader);
  begin
    aReader.ReadPersistent(fList);
  end;

  procedure TTest.ListToWriter(aWriter: TWriter);
  begin
    aWriter.WritePersistent(fList);
  end;

  procedure TTest.defineProperties(aFiler: TFiler);
  begin
    aFiler.defineProperty('the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising', ListFromReader, ListToWriter, true);
  end;

  constructor TTest.create(aOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;
    fList := TStringList.Create;
  end;

  destructor TTest.destroy;
  begin
    fList.Free;
    inherited;
  end;

var
  test: TTest;
  str1, str2: TMemoryStream;

const
  itm1 = 'aqwzsx';
  itm2 = 'edcrfv';

begin
  test := TTest.create(nil);
  str1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  str2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try

    // bin format passes
    test.list.add(itm1);
    test.list.add(itm2);
    str1.WriteComponent(test);
    str1.SaveToFile('bin.txt');
    str1.Clear;
    test.list.clear;
    str1.LoadFromFile('bin.txt');
    str1.ReadComponent(test);
    assert( test.list.strings[0] = itm1);
    assert( test.list.strings[1] = itm2);
    writeln('bin: zero killed');

    // text format does not
    str1.Clear;
    test.list.clear;
    test.list.add(itm1);
    test.list.add(itm2);
    str1.WriteComponent(test);
    str1.Position := 0;
    try
      ObjectBinaryToText(str1, str2);
    except
      writeln('ouch, it hurts (1)');
      exit;
    end;
    str2.SaveToFile('text.txt');
    str1.Clear;
    str2.Clear;
    test.list.clear;
    str1.LoadFromFile('text.txt');
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(str1, str2);
    except
      writeln('ouch, it hurts (2)');
      exit;
    end;
    str2.Position := 0;
    str2.ReadComponent(test);
    assert( test.list.strings[0] = itm1);
    assert( test.list.strings[1] = itm2);
    writeln('text: zero killed');

  finally
    sysutils.DeleteFile('bin.txt');
    sysutils.DeleteFile('text.txt');
    test.Free;
    str1.Free;
    str2.Free;
    readln;
  end;

end.
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

> bin: zero killed
>   ouch, it hurts (1)

Comment: "it fails" is not a problem description that's meaningful. In what way does it "fail"? What does "fails" mean? You've done a fine job of including the code, but *failed* (pun intended) to provide a problem description or ask a question.

Comment: You are using exception handling, but you are not outputting the error messages. Start by doing that, that will give you some clues as to what is going wrong. For instance, when I run your code in Delpih, the first error is an `EReadError` "Stream read error" exception. I don't know about FreePascal, but in Delphi, you can step through the RTL source code and find out exactly why the stream is not reading correctly.

Comment: alas, I program in Lazarus + FPC, the tag 'Delphi' has been added just to enlarge the audience. Actually I know that with Delphi I could check 'use debug dcu' and find the issue easily but it's not as simple with Laz. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your list property `published` and remove the call to `TFiler.DefineProperty()`, everything works correctly, as expected:

```
TTest = class(TComponent)
private
  fList: TStringList;
  procedure SetList(Value: TStringList);
public
  constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property list: TStringList read fList;
published
  property the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising: TStringList read fList write SetList;
end;
```

Here is what its DFM binary data looks like:

```
54 50 46 30 05 54 54 65 73 74 00 30 74 68 65 5F : TPF0.TTest.0the_
6C 69 73 74 5F 69 64 5F 6C 69 6B 65 74 6F 73 61 : list_id_liketosa
76 65 5F 77 69 74 68 6F 75 74 5F 70 75 62 6C 69 : ve_without_publi
73 69 6E 67 2E 53 74 72 69 6E 67 73 01 06 06 61 : sing.Strings...a
71 77 7A 73 78 06 06 65 64 63 72 66 76 00 00 00 : qwzsx..edcrfv...
```

And here is the text output:

```
object TTest
  the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising.Strings = (
    'aqwzsx'
    'edcrfv')
end
```

As you can see, there is a single string for the property name:

```
the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising.Strings
```

Internally, `TStream.ReadComponent()` reads that string and splits it on the `.` character, using RTTI to resolve `the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising` to the actual `TStringList` object, and then calling `DefineProperties('Strings')` on that object to let it stream its string list data, and all is fine.

`ObjectBinaryToText()` doesn't do that much work.  In fact, after looking at the RTL source code, it turns out that `ObjectBinaryToText()` (at least in Delphi, but I'm sure FreePascal is the same way) **DOES NOT** support custom streaming via `TComponent.DefineProperties()` at all (it never calls `DefineProperties()`)!.  That is the root of your problem.  `ObjectBinaryToText()` does not implement the full streaming system that `ReadComponent()` implements, only a subset of it.

However, in this case, everything is OK because `TStringList` writes its custom streaming data in a simple format that is easy for `ObjectBinaryToText()` to process.

When `ObjectBinaryToText()` reads the property name string, it writes it out as-is without parsing it in any way, then reads the next byte and processes it accordingly. `TStringList` uses this format:

```
vaList (TWriter.WriteListBegin())
vaString for each string (TWriter.WriteString())
vaNull (TWriter.WriteListEnd())
```

`ObjectBinaryToText()` recognizes those markers, so it knows that when it encounters `vaList` (hex `01`) that it needs to read values in a loop until it reads a `vaNull` (hex `00`), and it knows how to read a `vaString` (hex `06`) value.  So it has no trouble writing out the `Strings` data to the output text.

In the case of your `TTest` custom streaming, the DFM binary data it creates is a little bit different:

```
54 50 46 30 05 54 54 65 73 74 00 28 74 68 65 5F : TPF0.TTest.(the_
6C 69 73 74 5F 69 64 5F 6C 69 6B 65 74 6F 73 61 : list_id_liketosa
76 65 5F 77 69 74 68 6F 75 74 5F 70 75 62 6C 69 : ve_without_publi
73 69 6E 67 01 07 53 74 72 69 6E 67 73 01 06 06 : sing..Strings...
61 71 77 7A 73 78 06 06 65 64 63 72 66 76 00 00 : aqwzsx..edcrfv..
00 00                                           : ..
```

As you can see, there are two separate property name strings present:

```
the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising
```

```
Strings
```

When `ObjectBinaryToText()` reads the `the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising` string, it assumes it is the full property name and reads the next byte to determine the property's data type for reading.  That byte (hex `01`) is interpreted as `vaList`. The next byte (hex `07`) is interpreted as `vaIdent` (aka `not vaNull`), so it assumes a non-empty list of subproperties is being read (which it really isn't). It tries to read a `vaIdent` "property", where the next byte (hex `53`) is interpreted as the indent's byte length (which is it not), then it tries to read that many bytes (decimal 83) and fails.

In order to make your `TTest` custom streaming work correctly with `ObjectBinaryToText()`, you will have to produce a compatible DFM, by duplicating the same logic that `TStrings.DefineProperties()` implements (as its streaming methods are `private` and inaccessible), eg:

```
TTest = class(TComponent)
private
  fList: TStringList;
  procedure ListFromReader(aReader: TReader);
  procedure ListToWriter(aWriter: TWriter);
protected
  procedure DefineProperties(aFiler: TFiler); override;
public
  constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property list: TStringList read fList;
end;

procedure TTest.ListFromReader(aReader: TReader);
begin
  aReader.ReadListBegin;
  fList.BeginUpdate;
  try
    fList.Clear;
    while not aReader.EndOfList do fList.Add(aReader.ReadString);
  finally
    fList.EndUpdate;
  end;
  aReader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TTest.ListToWriter(aWriter: TWriter);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  aWriter.WriteListBegin;
  for I := 0 to fList.Count - 1 do aWriter.WriteString(fList[I]);
  aWriter.WriteListEnd;
end;

procedure TTest.DefineProperties(aFiler: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  aFiler.DefineProperty('the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising', ListFromReader, ListToWriter, fList.Count > 0);
end;

constructor TTest.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fList := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  fList.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Which produces this DFM binary data:

```
54 50 46 30 05 54 54 65 73 74 00 28 74 68 65 5F : TPF0.TTest.(the_
6C 69 73 74 5F 69 64 5F 6C 69 6B 65 74 6F 73 61 : list_id_liketosa
76 65 5F 77 69 74 68 6F 75 74 5F 70 75 62 6C 69 : ve_without_publi
73 69 6E 67 01 06 06 61 71 77 7A 73 78 06 06 65 : sing...aqwzsx..e
64 63 72 66 76 00 00 00                         : dcrfv...
```

Which produces this output text:

```
object TTest
  the_list_id_liketosave_without_publising = (
    'aqwzsx'
    'edcrfv')
end
```

That is simply the way `ObjectBinaryToText()` works, there is no getting around it.  It is not designed for general purpose custom streaming like you are trying to implement.  It is very specialized in what it can (and cannot) handle.  Remember, it is designed primarily for the IDE editor to display DFMs to users, so it relies on published components using simple streaming formats.  What you tried to implement is outside of its ability to parse.

What a difference a couple of bytes make, huh?

Comment: Thx for your expertise about my problem. I'd like to upvote your answer but I cant anymore because someone had the good idea to downvote my question...for him: peace man, the Q was not so badly exposed.